# Why is expressjs POST request returning [object Object]?

Tags: node.js, post

```
app.post("/api/orders", async(request, response) => {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    // Use the collection
    console.log("search options " + json(request));
  const col = db.collection("Orders");      
  // const inserted = await col.insertOne();
   response.send("thanks")
   } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
}

 
});
```

/

```
let orderData = {subject: "subject", location: "location", price:"price", spaces: "spaces"};
const optionsPOST = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(orderData)

};
console.log(JSON.stringify(orderData))
fetch("/api/orders", optionsPOST);
```

I am trying to post some data that then is added to mongodb atlas, however, when I post my data I get undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a simple fetch request

```
fetch('/api/orders', optionsPOST)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

This should also help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch